# Hybrid mobile app : Store sensible data on client side

Tags: cordova, security, web-applications

I am creating a web application using Cordova framework.
My project is organized as following :

```
root
----- hooks
----- platforms
----- plugins
----- res
----- www
--------- css
--------- img
--------- js
--------- res
--------- spec
```

In my js folder, i need to perform a https request to a distant server to perform a login. In my app, i need to store the most securely possible the SERVER_URL, ther USERNAME and PASSWORD.

Today, these data are written directly as Strings in my js files.

What is the best way to store these sensible data into a web app project ?

Comment: Do you want to authenticate your user (the person) or the app itself? Note that the latter is impossible, and for the first you don't store the user credentials in js files.

Comment: It's rhe personn that i want to authenticate. Once the login is done, i get a sessionid in response that is used for all requests later

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do would be OAuth2. When your user first logs on, he would provide a username and password (if initial authentication is password based; it usually is), and then the server would provide him with an access token specific for the user and the device. Your app would only store the access token for the user, and your app should store it in a reasonably secure place, ie. the keychain/keystore solution on the mobile platform. Note that it would still be a very relevant threat that an attacker gets hold of the access token, so from time to time, it should be invalidated on the server and a new one issued. This could be transparent for the user as long as everything goes as intended. Also there should be a facility for the user to review active access tokens (aka. his "devices") and remove access from ones that he doesn't want to be able to access his data anymore (ie. remove a device in case of a compromise). As an additional security control, you could send emails when a new access token is granted (ie. a new device is added), etc.

If all this is not in place, and your user authenticates directly with his username and password to receive a plain old session id, you can treat that as a kind of an access token too. Technically, it is a form of an access token after all. You can store it in keystore if you want, but you need to be aware that it is at risk there and can potentially be stolen by an attacker, in which case your user will probably have no idea at all or no way to invalidate the session. If you mitigate these risks, you will pretty much end up with the proper solution above. :)

You should not store the password for your users in any way on the client.

The server url is not (and should not be) a secret. Anyone using the app can very easily find out anyway.